# Sharp vs rounded (tomed) vertical stroke in kanjis

Tags: kanji, handwriting, calligraphy

How can I know for sure in what situation I should use sharp vertical line and in what situation I should use rounded vertical line?

For example, from videos on youtube I do know for sure that vertical line in 申 is sharp and I do know for sure, that vertical line in 木 is rounded.

Is there some rule or hint or tip on defining myself when it is sharp and when it is rounded (tomed)?

My question is about vertical lines only.

[image]

[image]

Comment: @Ambo100 Thank you that you added #calligraphy tag, but I do not understand why you deleted #handwriting tag. My question is about handwriting too. I do handwrite kanjies, but I do not do calligraphy (e.g. I do not use brushes and ink). I just use gel pen.

Comment: probably because you showed a picture of calligraphy

Comment: @Leebo Ok, added screenshot of how vertical lines are different in handwriting with gel pen in a study notebook.

Comment: @Tchibi-kun You may know this, but most people don’t distinguish sharp lines from rounded ones even when they write formal texts.

Comment: What's "tomed"? Is it an English word?

Comment: tome <- 止め, as in とめ、はね、はらい, perhaps?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

A recent guideline from 文化庁 clearly says this distinction is not important in most cases. See page 53 of [this PDF](http://www.bunka.go.jp/koho_hodo_oshirase/hodohappyo/pdf/2016022902.pdf) (常用漢字表の字体・字形に関する指針（報告）（案）） (2016):

> [image]

As for 木, you can also use はね ([image: example]).

Some recent elementary school teachers are extremely strict on this kind of thing, which has [caused much controversy](https://matomedane.jp/page/23877). Outside school, very few adults care about this. If you want examples for practice, find some [教科書体](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/search?tab=votes&q=%E6%95%99%E7%A7%91%E6%9B%B8%E4%BD%93) font.

(The guideline above is for the general public. Professional calligraphers and historians may have their own opinions.)